# How To Solve MySqlException: Expected end of data packet Problem?

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-web-services

I wanted to use the SELECT syntax to import data in conjunction with Unity and AWS RDS, but this is not due to an error in MySqlException: Expected end of data packet.

Is there a solution? Current cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); is failing.

I am new to Unity to AWS RDS Interlink so I don't know what problem is this. i guess this problem comes from incoming packets of database's end of data, not my source code.

anyone knows the solution? your help is greatly appreciated. i been trying for 5 days but cannot solve.

```
void Awake()
{
    string connectionString = "Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;User ID=;Password=;Charset=utf8";

    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        Debug.Log("Success");

        string query = "SELECT * FROM Account";

        MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 99999;
        cmd.CommandText = "USP_WAIT";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Debug.Log(cmd);
    }
}
```

```
MySqlException: Expected end of data packet
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.CheckEOF () (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadEOF () (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnsData (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlField[] columns) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetColumns (System.Int32 count) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.LoadColumns (System.Int32 numCols) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet..ctor (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver d, System.Int32 statementId, System.Int32 numCols) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult (System.Int32 statementId) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult () (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
Rethrow as MySqlException: Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult () (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Close () (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ResetReader () (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) (at <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0)
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal (System.Data.DataSet dataset, System.Data.DataTable[] datatables, System.Int32 startRecord, System.Int32 maxRecords, System.String srcTable, System.Data.IDbCommand command, System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) (at <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0)
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill (System.Data.DataTable[] dataTables, System.Int32 startRecord, System.Int32 maxRecords, System.Data.IDbCommand command, System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) (at <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0)
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill (System.Data.DataTable dataTable) (at <290425a50ff84a639f8c060e2d4530f6>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ISSchemaProvider.GetTable (System.String sql) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ISSchemaProvider.Query (System.String table_name, System.String initial_where, System.String[] keys, System.String[] values) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ISSchemaProvider.GetProcedures (System.String[] restrictions) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ISSchemaProvider.GetSchemaInternal (System.String collection, System.String[] restrictions) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.SchemaProvider.GetSchema (System.String collection, System.String[] restrictions) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.GetSchema (System.String collectionName, System.String[] restrictionValues) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ProcedureCache.GetProcData (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection, System.String spName) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ProcedureCache.AddNew (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection, System.String spName) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ProcedureCache.GetProcedure (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn, System.String spName, System.String cacheKey) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.GetParameters (System.String procName, System.Data.DataTable& proceduresTable, System.Data.DataTable& parametersTable) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.Resolve (System.Boolean preparing) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader () (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () (at <326e9aab93854e739606c3572c385a34>:0)
DatabaseConnection.Awake () (at Assets/Scripts/DatabaseConnection.cs:34)
```

Comment: You set the `CommandText` to `query` and then change it to `"USP_WAIT"` without executing `query`, so `"USP_WAIT"` is the only thing you execute. It's unlikely that's the entirety of the problem, but it can't be what you intended to do, either.

Comment: Thank you for your help but Without `USP_WAIT` and `StoredProcedure`, `Timeout` would not work, and when that happens, this error was thrown in. `"Connection failed because there was no response from the incidentized member, or the connection was lost because the host did not notice."` What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: That should've been your question. What you posted is an XY problem. `Timeout` is a related to the command, not the connection, and the original error message is related to the connection.

Comment: In fact, USP_WAIT sounds suspicious. Without knowing what it does, its name suggests something that you *absolutely do not* want a stored procedure to do.

Comment: Oh.... So, if I post a new question, can I get an answer?

Comment: You'll have a ***far*** better chance with that than with the question you asked.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your help.